# pandas - List data being used to calculate rolling?

Tags: python, pandas

How would I list the values being used in:

```
m1df['close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).mean()
```

I am using a single `database` to load data into a `dataframe` and somehow the values returned by two different `scripts` for the same line of code above is different.

Going crazy checking the details.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `m1df['close']` to just get the values in the `close` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can "debug" it with 'apply':

```
m1df['close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).apply(lambda w: print(w) or w.mean(), raw=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
m1df['close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).mean().tolist()
```

If you need the unique values:

```
m1df['close'].rolling(window=60, min_periods=60).mean().unique()
```